# Raid set add member: com.apple.StorageKit error 118

Tags: mojave, raid

I have a failed RAID set, and am trying to add a replacement drive.  Every time I try to repair, add member, or add spare, it fails immediately with com.apple.StorageKit error 118.  Does anyone know what this error means?  Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Are you booted into the Recovery Partition or Internet Recovery? Are you attempting to erase the partition instead of the top level disk? You need to erase the disk.

Comment: No, computer is running in normal mode.  After I select repair, add member, or add spare, it lets me select which disk to add.  I have two different empty disks and get the same error on both.  It only allows the two empty disks to be selected.  After I select the disk is when the error comes.  Note that if I create a new raid set and select the two disks, it does successfully create the raid set.  But it fails each time I try to add one of the empty disks to the existing raid set.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your error?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/guynentapyjn21i/Untitled.png

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite late to answer but I came across the same error today while trying to add a new member to a failed RAID1 volume.

The issue is, Disk Utility doesn't tell you the whole story.

Running the same operation through the terminal will give you the correct error message when executing `diskutil appleRAID add member diskX /Volumes/RaidVolumeName`:

`Error: -69797: The RAID set cannot be modified because it is currently rebuilding`

To avoid getting this error, you need to disable autorebuild on the RAID disk:
`diskutil appleRAID update AutoRebuild 0 diskX` (diskX is the virtual raid disk)

Then reboot.

After you reboot, it won't be rebuilding anymore and you can add the member, either via Terminal, or Disk Utility.

HTH others.